# Angular2 TypeError: cannot read property 'compilerOptions' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I got TypeError:

> cannot read property 'compilerOptions' of undefined

Here is my compilerOptions code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,

  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What have you done till now? Please share your code

Comment: thanks for supporting Mikkel..now its working The error is in JSON format i have done this.

Answer (score 3):

First, your JSON format is wrong in your application's .tsconfig.json. There is a `,` in 8th line.

```
"noEmitHelpers": true, // <-- trailing comma in tscofing breaks ts compile
```

Comment: But from where you are calling this data? Please add that code